# What does the term "vendoring" or "to vendor" mean for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Examples:
"Vendoring Rails application at test/dummy"
"What is the recommended way of vendoring Rails for production?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "vendoring"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217488/what-is-vendoring)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vendoring is the moving of all 3rd party items such as plugins, gems and even rails into the `/vendor` directory.
This is one method for ensuring 
that all files are deployed to the production server the same as the dev environment.

Best way to do this is either:

```
  rake gems:unpack
```

Or

```
  rake rails:freeze:gems
```

Use `rake -T` to see a full list of rake tasks.