# Count number of lines in a GitHub repository without cloning

Tags: git, github, cloud

There are similar questions but all of them need you to clone repository and then run some utility on it. 
I need a web-service which can give me those stats (something like using an URL e.g. `http://my-sloc-counter.com/project1` to get SLOC stats for project1 from GitHub)

Comment: Specific for github, or is github just an example?

Comment: Well, currently Git = GitHub on 99% of cases, so, yes specific for github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is browser extension for Google Chrome named [Gloc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-gloc/kaodcnpebhdbpaeeemkiobcokcnegdki).

Answer (score 6):

For GitHub specifically, you have a possibility to compute an *approximation* of that data (LOC: Lines of Code) through the [GitHub Statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/).

You can see an example in "[Can you get the number of lines of code from a GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154303/6309)", which does *not* involve cloning the repo.

---

More recently, you have the project [`jolav/codetabs`](https://github.com/jolav/codetabs) (initally mentioned by [Sclerosis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9015002/sclerosis)), based on  [Curtis Gagliardi `cgag/loc`](https://github.com/cgag/loc) for counting lines of code.
It includes a service for counting lines for any public GitHub repository:
[codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html](https://codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html).

Example for my project: https://api.codetabs.com/v1/loc?github=vonc/seec

---

Problem (for both solutions): they do count the lines of *all* files inside a repo, so if you have [vendored files like in a Go project](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories), you will have a hard time distinguishing what *you* wrote from [what you have vendored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643873/6309).

Comment: I was hoping for a solution which doesn't need much coding.

Comment: @mahdix I understand, but there is no direct way to get that information from a GitHub repo at this time. Cloning the repo (shallow clone if needed) remains the most precise and practical way to get that data.