# Different Data records about open source projects

Tags: github, open-source

While working on my thesis project which has analyzing open source projects as a part of it, I found that different websites provide completely different records about some projects.

Lets take for example: **Apache Camel**.
Regarding openhub.net  [Apache Camel](https://www.openhub.net/p/camel)  has 274 contributors, while in Github it has only 199 Contributors [Apache Camel on Githup](https://github.com/apache/camel)

So the question is: which one to trust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub only monitors activities on the master branch.
And it is a mirror of the actual repo https://www.openhub.net/p/camel, which has many branches.

See "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)" for the GitHub contribution policy.

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:
>
> - The commits were made within the past year.
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made in the repository's default branch (usually **`master`**)

That openhub repo does count contribution done on all branches.

Comment: Well, that make sense! Another question: do you have any idea about the percentage of languges? lets say that Apache Camel has 87% written in java, is that counted for the last version release of the project? or is it for the project generally? despite the version?

Comment: Same also for project size and number of code lines?

Comment: You can see on GitHub the % of languages (98.2% Java for https://github.com/apache/camel) See https://github.com/github/linguist, based on the current commit of the master branch.

Comment: @user5923402 same deal for loc (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35933176/6309). The GitHub stats API https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/ does mention "Repository statistics are cached by the SHA of the repository's default branch, which is usually master; pushing to the default branch resets the statistics cache."

Comment: I believe that I should relay on openhub, as it gives general records instead of the master branch only !

thanks for your help :)