# Run CLI tool on a github repo without cloning

Tags: javascript, github, cloc

This is probably a very silly question but I'm going to ask it anyway.

I am writing a Node app which gives a user a bunch of stats about their repos. I wanted to use [codetabs](https://codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html) but I would prefer to not have a limit. Usually you would just clone the repo and use something like [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) to get the results. So is there a way to run CLI tools on github repositories without cloning it? Or is there another service like codetabs without a limit?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932418/count-number-of-lines-in-a-github-repository-without-cloning

Comment: hey @ceving, thanks for the info, is there generally a way to run CLI tools without cloning?