# How can i save js, css in cache from Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, server, strapi

i have some files from node_modules they need to be saved in cache because i am getting this information

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Vhs.png)

to get this information i audited with lighthouse this is the web https://www.webpagetest.org/

this is the final result, "cache static content" is the **wrong**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5YOz.png)

i am working with Gatsby, i found this information about my problem https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/caching/#javascript-and-css  but i am not sure how can i use it or should i use another library? i dont have idea how can i cache

i think i should use these properties:

```
The cache-control header should be cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

this is my file gatsby-config

```
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-top-layout',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'assets',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
      options: {
        precachePages: ['/projects/'],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-material-ui',
```

my propuse to do this is solve this problem, there are a blank space when i reload the web application

[blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRnyj.png)

Comment: You're going to need to send these HTTP headers from your web server not your static content (gatsby).  What web server are you using?

Comment: @nita i am using firebase

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby generates static content. It doesn't handle sending HTTP responses. That's going to be a web server (or in your case firebase).

Checkout the docs for sending headers on firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

You'll need something like:

```yaml
"hosting": {
  "headers": [ {
    "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "cache-control",
      "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

This caches font files which is generally safe because fonts change very rarely.

You can add `js` and `css` to that list if you want as well. Keep in mind that you'll need to change the names of an js and css files or the browser will wait 1 year before reloading them.

Comment: @nita i can not change their names because of they belong to node_modules

Comment: What are they called? You can probably modify the "source" section to include them specifically.

Comment: @nita they are in my first image

Comment: @brucelee you can't control the headers sent by other websites. Your options are avoiding these dependencies or (if possible) vendoring them so your headers apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217488/what-is-vendoring.

Comment: @nita how can i improve my app, i optimized the images, i refactored my code, but the wrong blank space keeps showing, i edited my question i put a new image

Comment: webpagetest isn't the arbiter of good web development. Is your page fast enough for your users? Check marks on some webpage aren't a good end goal but just a list of possible improvements. If you have a more specific question feel free to ask it "how can i improve my app" isn't enough to help you.