# What does "vendoring" mean in Go?

Tags: go, terminology

When learning about Go's dependency management, I often hear the term "vendor" used as a verb. Example: "The dependencies that your application vendors..."

What does it mean to **vendor a dependency** in this context?

---

Examples:

> "Dependencies that are vendored with your application"

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#declare-app-dependencies

> "godep will write the vendored code"

Source: https://github.com/tools/godep#go-15-vendor-experiment

---

*Follow-up questions:*

- Is this related to [vendoring in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378921/what-does-the-term-vendoring-or-to-vendor-mean-for-ruby-on-rails)?
- Is this term fully defined in the [Go 1.5 Vendor Experiment](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bz5-UB7g2uPBdOx-rw5t9MxJwkfpx90cqG9AFL0JAYo/edit), or is there a separate conventional definition?

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [Package version management in Go 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775722/package-version-management-in-go-1-5)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Defined [here](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/10/manage-dependencies-with-godep.html) for Go as:

> Vendoring is the act of making your own copy of the 3rd party packages
>   your project is using. Those copies are traditionally placed inside
>   each project and then saved in the project repository.

I don't know squirt about Ruby.

Essentially you're taking a package, storing it within your own project and using that version to build from. I liken it to how you might have a "vendors" folder where you put third party css or js when building a web page.

Comment: The definition is same as in a Ruby context.