# What does "inconsistent vendoring" mean in Go?

Tags: go, govendor

I'm getting this inconsistent vendoring error and I'm a total Go newbie. Can anyone explain to me how go.mod interacts with vendor/modules.txt? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109393/what-does-vendoring-mean-in-go) helpful, and now I'm wondering if I should even have a vendor directory. Would that be created by running `go mod vendor`? I inherited this project and it already has the vendor directory in git.

Here's the relevant part of my go.mod file -

```
module mymodule

go 1.17

require (
        gopkg.in/redis.v5 v5.2.9
)
```

And then the related error message:

```
go: inconsistent vendoring
gopkg.in/redis.v5@v5.2.9: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
```

In vendor/modules.txt I have:

```
#gopkg.in/redis.v5 v5.2.9
gopkg.in/redis.v5
gopkg.in/redis.v5/internal
gopkg.in/redis.v5/internal/consistenthash
gopkg.in/redis.v5/internal/hashtag
gopkg.in/redis.v5/internal/pool
gopkg.in/redis.v5/internal/proto
```

For what it's worth I'm getting this error for every dependency in my go.mod file, I just included the one about redis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`go.mod` and `vendor/modules.txt` (if present) must be in sync.

Whenever `go.mod` changes and there is a `vendor` directory, `go mod vendor` needs to be run to update the contents of the `vendor` directory.

All direct dependencies (not marked `// implicit` in `go.mod`) are "explicit" and marked accordingly in `vendor/modules.txt` starting from Go 1.14.

After running `go mod vendor` notice the new line `## explicit` added after the package reference:

```
#gopkg.in/redis.v5 v5.2.9
## explicit
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unable to find this information elsewhere.  In my case I upgraded Go from 1.10 to 1.16 and saw this error with an otherwise synced vendor folder because the original modules.txt did not have `## explicit`.  Adding those lines solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @rustyx's answer, in order to fix this error, I **deleted** the `vendor` folder and then I ran again `go mod vendor`, and the error disappeared.

Comment: It works for me. When `inconsistent vendoring` occurs, just runing `go mod vendor`  does not works for me, but the command works after I delete the vendor folder.

Comment: vendor folder not recreated for me on this - how to recreate it?!

Answer (score 0):

For me updating the version solved the issue. I was running go1.16 and I updated to go1.18.2. Before the update I tried go mod vendor and also updating the modules.txt didn't work then, I started ignoring the vendor directory by running
go build -mod=mod to build the application or go run -mod=mod main.go to run the main.go file